# php multiple table changes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to generate a php script that will carry out a sequential backup and update/renaming a number of MySql tables. Can I do this in a single query or will I need to generate a query for each action?

I need the script to do the following in order

1. DROP TABLE backup2
2. RENAME TABLE backup1 TO backup2
3. RENAME TABLE main TO backup1
4. COPY TABLE incomingmain TO main
5. TRUNCATE TABLE incomingmain

In practice the TABLE incomingmain will be populated from an external import before the TABLE update sequence above is carried out.

Can any one advise please how I structure this after connecting to the database?

Comment: If you're using `mysqli` you can use [mysqli::multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to send all the queries as one string.

Comment: @Alexander. This is not true. Check out PDO and exec function. This would work perfectly fine wrapped with a Transaction

Comment: @AlexandrPerfilov - yes you can. Both `mysqli` and `PDO` have functions for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off to use a `mysqli::multi_query()`.

It also depends on the return values, meaning are you going to check for errors or blindly run them all at once? If I am you, I would code it sequentially, just because it will look much cleaner from a coding point of view.

Comment: Can you give some pointers how to code it sequentially, with error checking at each point please.